# How can I have Raw HTML inside a JsonConvert's SerializeObject()?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, json.net

I'm trying to recreate the following JavaScript code using Newtonsoft's parser:

```
var nav = { container: $('.ux-navigation-control'), manual: true, validate: true };
```

Trying to use `Html.Raw` inside Newtonsoft like:

```
var nav = @(new HtmlString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                                                      {
                                                          container = Html.Raw("$('.ux-navigation-control')"),
                                                          manual = true,
                                                          validate = true
                                                      }))) ;
```

Returns an empty object instead of the desired expression:

```
var nav = {"container":{},"manual":true,"validate":true} ;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.ux-navigation-control')` isn't valid JSON, so most if not all JSON parsers will throw this out. You should just return the selector instead and do some post-processing on the client side, like so:

```
$.getJSON('/myurl', function(nav) {
  nav.container = $(nav.container);
  // do something else with nav
});
```

Comment: I see. I was really trying to avoid this, but oh well. :)

Comment: I mean, you can generate _javascript_ that looks like that, and as long as it's being consumed as javascript source code then you'll be fine. But then you won't be able to use your fancy JSON generator  =)